# is there a way i can either insert a character into a line or substitute and arbitrary character with itself plus some other carachter(s) in sed?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex, sed

like say i have a string of numbers that constitute a phone number and are like so

##########

and i want to format them like :

###-###-####

insert only puts in new lines, and i dont know how to make say an expression like

sed (s/[0-9]/TheNumberIFound-/)//3//6

so is there some way i can ask sed to just add something after a matched pattern, or to replace the matched pattern with itself plus some other char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "1234567890" | sed -re 's/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/\1-\2-\3/g'
123-456-7890
```

- `[0-9]` does match any digit in one position in the phone number.
- `{3}` tells sed to match the pattern prepended to this, `3` times.
- The `(` and `)` (parentheses) surrounding the three repeats of these logs the matched numbers in "memories"
  the "memories" are then "recalled" with `\1` for the first parenthese, `\2` for the second and so on.
- Therefore `\1-\2-\3` makes your reformatted phone number.
- Add the `g` at the end to make sed do this more than once per line.

*Intentionally attempted to keep language at 'noob' level ;-p*

Comment: while yes this does work, i can't get it to work when it's in a script. 
without the single quotes it doesnt work properly, with them i get an error.

Comment: Doublequotes `"` should also work. Without quotes you will have the command shell (e.g. bash) attempting to interpret your typing. `"` allows the shell to substitute `$variable` or `${variable}` for you - but note that sed uses `$` for matching end-of-line; which may become a problem.

Comment: it wasn't the quotes that were at fault, when in my script it wasn't running with them with an error of unknown command"'"(or, when i used double quotes as suggested """) but rather, it was that neither in your answer, nor in my script did we escape the curly braces (even though i did this when i tested the command on an echo just to make sure it worked, just mustn't have registered in my mind). all's good now. thanks for your help.

Comment: `-r` is there to eliminate the need for the extensive \'s.

Comment: sed was disallowing me from using any other options after i used the -f option, as it was attempting to interpret them as commands